# How do I get the results of memor_usage in the form of a dictionary?

Tags: python, profiler, memory-profiling

I need to know what is the memory usage of my Machine Learning model.
I am using memit from memory_profiler as follows.

```
from memory_profiler import profile
from memory_profiler import memory_usage


def MLmodel (X_train, y_train):
   model = linearregression ()
   model.fit(X_train,Y_train)
return model

trainmemory = % memit -o MLmodel (X_train, y_train)
```

the result is:

```
peak memory: 458.21 MiB, increment: 0.00 MiB
```

now I want to get a dictionary like this:

```
dic_memory = {'peak memory': 458.21 MiB, 'increment': 0.00 MiB }
```

I do not know how can I get the peak memory and increment separately and put them in a dictionary.